# Printing 2 half landscape page in 1 letter size sheet using ITextSharp

Tags: model-view-controller, itext, mvcrazortopdf

I'm Generating my PDF file using MvcRazorToPdf and ITextSharp. My code is like this:

```
public ActionResult Print()
{
    var model = new recordListModel();
    model.records = db.Records.Select(x => new recordModel { 
        Id = x.Id,
        Date = x.Date,
        PaidTo = x.PaidTo,
        CheckNo = x.CheckNo,
        Payor = x.Payor
    }).ToList();

    return new PdfActionResult(model, (writer, document) =>
    {
        document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(612f, 396f, 90));
        document.NewPage();
    });
}
```

When PDf is generated it will display for example 2 landscape pages that is a half of letter size sheet that you will see in this line of code:

```
document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(612f, 396f, 90)); // half of letter size
```

But when i print it the first page is printed in a whole sheet and the second page also printed in a whole sheet.

How can i print this 2 landscape pages in one sheet?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's caused by a printer setting in the PDF viewer you are using. Unfortunately, the PDF specification doesn't allow you to change this printer setting in the PDF viewer. You have 2 options: (1) change the printer setting manually in your PDF viewer, or (2) 2-up your PDF (2-up is a special case of N-up; N-upping is a process in which you copy several pages to a single page: 2-up, 4-up, 8-up, 16-up, and so on).

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Lowagie, but how to use N-up?

Comment: By using [NUpTool](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=115) as an example.

Comment: Wow you wrote the code of NUpTool? I'm sorry but can you give me an example on how to implement NUpTool.cs on my code?

Comment: All the examples of the iText in Action book were ported to C#. The NUpTool is part of chapter 6, hence you can find the iTextSharp version of that example here: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06